# Flutter App does not write JSON to local text file in Android 13

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new to flutter and ran into an issue i can't figure out. I'm trying to learn the basics and store a JSON file locally that holds just a few settings for now for an app. Basically an color information and if it's a light or dark theme. I follow the approach path_provider & dart.io as shown in

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Everything works fine when I built a windows app with Visual Studio Code, and the data gets stored successfully and can be retrieved without issue. However, when I built an apk with Android Studio or Visual Studio Code the app looks fine on first glance but the JSON file can't be accessed when I close and reopen the app. It looks like the file is not written. I use getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() from the path_provider package to get the directory independent of OS. What I don't understand is, I use the same path to write and read an SQL database which works with sqflite and the json is written and accessed in windows with no problem either.

Is there something that prevents me from writing certain files to the documents folder in Android 13 ? Do i have to request a permission to write non-databases to local file in android? As i understood it getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() would return the AppData directory that only the app can access, and which is specifically for storing info like this.

Any help that helps me understand whats going wrong would be apreciated.
Thanks

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

class Config {
  Color primaryColor;
  bool light;

  Config(this.primaryColor, this.light);

  Config.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : primaryColor = Color(json['primaryColor']),
        light = json['light'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'primaryColor': primaryColor.value,
        'light': light,
      };

  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/config.json');
  }

  Future<void> writeConfigToFile() async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    file.writeAsString(json.encode(toJson()));
  }

  Future<Config> getSettingsFromFile() async {
    try {
      final settingsFile = await _localFile;
      final jsonString = await settingsFile.readAsString();
      Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(jsonString);
      return Config.fromJson(data);
    } catch (e) {
      // If encountering an error, return default, blue light theme
      return Config(Colors.blue, true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just remembered this one and that i found a solution. It wasn't that the file wasn't written but it didn't load in time. The solution was to introduce a 'WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();' right at the beginning before loading the file with await ... and then the rest of the app. Having the file load right at the beginning does not work even if followed by the 'WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();'